# POJO deserialization property of interface type withoud impementation class with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a problem with deserialization json into POJO class which looks like this:

```
@Data
public class Foo {
   private String fieldA;
   private String fieldB;
   private IBar fieldC; 
}
```

`IBar` is an interface which defines getters for some classes. One of the solutions what I found is to use `@JsonDeserialize(as = BarImpl.class)` where `BarImpl` will implement `IBar` interface. Problem is classes which implement that interface (for instance `BarImpl`) are in another maven module where I don't have access from current module so I cannot use one of this impl classes in that annotation. Can you tell me if there is another solution?

Thank you in advice.

Comment: Can't you just @JsonIgnore that field?  It can't have any data coming from the json. The field will still exist in the POJO object created.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean deserialization? You'll need a concrete implementation of your interface if Jackson's going to be able to create Java objects for you.

- deserialization = Json String -> Java object
- serialization = Java object -> Json String

When serializing Jackson will use the runtime class of the object, so it will use the actual implementations rather than attempt to use the interface. If you want to customize this you can add a serializer for your interface. You'll need to decide exactly what you want to write out.

```
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(IBar.class, new JsonSerializer<IBar>() {

            @Override
            public void serialize(IBar value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeStringField("fieldName", value.getFieldName());
                gen.writeEndObject();
            }


        });
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Yes I mean deserialization. We send our objects between multiple systems serialized, so I also need deserialize it. With serialization I don't have troubles because I serialize specific class with implement IBar interface.